# How are threads different from process in terms of how they are executed on hardware level?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was wondering how the threads are executed on hardware level, like a process would run on a single processing core and make a context switch on the processor and the MMU in order to switch between processes. How do threads switch? Secondly when we create/spawn a new thread will it be seen as a new process would for the processor and be scheduled as a process would?

Also when should one use threads and when a new process?

I know I probably am sounding dumb right now, that's because I have massive gaps in my knowledge that I would like fill. Thanks in advance for taking the time and explaining things to me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different methods for concurrency. The threading module creates threads within the same Python process and switches between them, this means they're not really running at the same time. The same happens with the Asyncio module, however this has the additional feature of setting when a thread can be switched.

Then there is the multiprocessing module which creates a separate Python process per thread. This means that the threads will not have access to shared memory but can mean that the processes run on different CPU cores and therefore can provide a performance improvement for CPU bound tasks.

Regarding when to use new threads a good rule of thumb would be:

- For I/O bound problems, use threading or async I/O. This is because you're waiting on responses from something external, like a database or browser, and this waiting time can instead be filled by another thread running it's task.
- For CPU bound problems use multiprocessing. This can run multiple Python processes on separate cores at the same time.

Disclaimer: Threading is not always a solution and you should first determine whether it is necessary and then look to implement the solution.

Comment: This is a good answer. I would only add that Python's threads behavior is specific to languages with a GIL (like Python or Ruby) or on top of other VMs which do not allow efficient data sharing (like V8 JavaScript engine). In languages compiled to native code, threads can run in true parallel, not merely concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:  "a *thread* is part of a *process."*

A "process" owns resources such as memory, open file-handles and network ports, and so on.  All of these resources are then available to every "thread" which the process owns.  (By definition, every "process" always contains at least one ("main") "thread.")

CPUs and cores, then, execute these "threads," in the context of the "process" which they belong to.

On a multi-CPU/multi-core system, it is therefore possible that more than one thread belonging to a particular process *really is* executing in parallel.  Although you can never be sure.

Also:  in the context of an interpreter-based programming language system like Python, the actual situation is a little bit more complicated "behind the scenes," because the Python interpreter context does exist and will be seen by all of the Python threads.  This does add a slight amount of additional overhead so that it all "just works."

Comment: Okay, I understand most of it. I am wondering if these threads are seen as processes by the processor(by seen I mean just seen like they have their own PC and other registers)? I read somewhere that threads like processes needs context switching on processor and to switch between them. And how switching work between threads.

Comment: @TheWhiteFang, Re, "...seen as processes by the processor..." A CPU dosn't know what "thread" or "process" means. It just executes instructions. An OS-level _thread_ is an object containing values to be loaded into a CPU's registers to make it resume executing from a particular point in the instruction stream. An OS-level _process_ is an object representing resources (memory, open files, etc.) that one or more threads are allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

On the OS level, threads are units of execution that share the same resources (memory, file descriptors, etc). Groups of threads that belong to different processes are isolated from each other, can't access resources across the process boundary. You can think of a "just process" as a single thread, not unlike any other thread.

OS threads are scheduled like you would expect: if there are several cores, they can run in parallel; if there are more threads / processes ready to run than there are cores, some threads get preempted after some time, paused, and another thread has a chance to run on that core.

*In Python,* though, the difference between threads (`threading` module) and processes (`multiproceessing` module) is *drastic.*

Python runs in a VM. Threads run within that VM. Objects within the VM are reference-counted, and also are unsafe to concurrently modify. So OS thread scheduling which can preempt one thread in the middle of a VM instruction modifying an object, and give control to another object that accesses the same object, will result in corruption.

This is why the [global interpreter lock aka GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) exists. It basically prevents any computational parallelism between Python "threads": only one thread can proceed at a time, no matter how many CPU cores you have. Python threads are only good for waiting for I/O.

Unlike that, `multiprocessing` runs a parallel VM (Python interpreter) and shares select pieces of data with it in a safe way (by copying, or using shared memory). Such parallel processes *can* run in parallel and utilize multiple CPU cores.

In short: Python threads ≠ OS threads.